# Type checking failure when assigning objects with additional properties to deep structure

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create an object that should follow a specific structure in TypeScript. However, I'm not getting any type warnings when I add properties that are not part of the defined structure.

Here's the code snippet that demonstrates the issue:

```js
export enum Type {
    SSH = 'SSH',
    SCP = 'SCP',
    HTTP = 'HTTP',
}

export type CredentialsPerType = {
    [T in Type]?: Credentials;
};

export interface Credentials {
    port: string;
    username: string;
    password: string;
}

function typeCheckingNotWorking() {
    for (let type of [Type.SSH, Type.SCP]) {
        const credentialsPerType: CredentialsPerType = {
            [type]: {
                port: '443',
                username: 'user',
                password: 'password',
                foo: 'bar'  // Why there is no TS error?
            }
        }
    }
}

function typeCheckingWorking() {
    for (let type of [Type.SSH, Type.SCP]) {
        const credentials: Credentials = {
                port: '443',
                username: 'user',
                password: 'password',
                foo: 'bar' // Here we have error
            }

        const credentialsPerType: CredentialsPerType = {
            [type]: credentials,
        }
    }
}
```

You can play with the code on the TypeScript playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=43&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwCoE8zDgbwCg4S4BlMgCTgF44ByCy%20gGmNLIGEAFWhr7q3YlKGDLzr1R4oQF9ChUJFhwYOPJyjAAJkhgBLAIYAbAM7dgUbLj5FScANoY4%20xJnUBdAPwAuOJp09IzMAbkJZMMVwaHhXGEsAM0MAYw0tXUQDE1MCYThlGD9TGChXAHMw%202RTS0RDVGAikvLK0jBDU1MAd2htJtLECvCFBOREZIMINzVcTgALYGSAa3KAOQgYAHVoFcGACgBKXPsE6Dg942B4GbwIBMdrYAA6JhZ3XBeeDyO7e1JkqbFODJdJBbIWKzqPwBDJZMwQx62PJ-UgOG4ePy-FHY-IxPz0AAsBIAzEIcTjqrV6o0GJSoGTySj2p0elA%20gxmd1egzGScIBB8QAjQz0kgAejFcE2cywqgWWhcOUQG0wZAQUCg0C8yOx8hxetI8nkhFG40m03U80WuzK2ygNsOx1Ipyg50u13UcDuD3ULyob0en243ydKIBiCBIMCmWCpmhoJj2SRvL%20BXxRNJbBTVRqUDqDXxdJ52c5rPZ9FL3Kz2ZIpwFDGFoolcEoljwXTwc0MADc8JZNVAdSjjTjw5GE3DzJZHvHo5OEZ66FjyWjPH4o7DY9Xh3kjUA).

I expect that when assigning an object to `credentialsPerType` with additional properties that are not part of the `Credentials` interface, TypeScript should raise a type error. However, I don't receive any error or warning in this case.

Why is the type checking not working as expected in this scenario?

Comment: @wonderflame thanks. You can write it down as an answer and it will be accepted.

Comment: my answer was irrelevant. I think there is an issue with the `for of`. If you try to declare `type` as `let type: Type = Type.SSH` everything works as expected. I'm not sure about the reason at the moment

Comment: It's even worse than extra properties (which isn't really a type safety issue). You could completely misspell property names and it would be fine, or put the wrong property type in there, and it *still* wouldn't error.  It's an unfortunate interaction of multiple bugs or limitations in TypeScript.  #13948 and #27144 are the main causes, with some related offshoots like #38663.  See the linked question and answer for more information.